# Localhost Page Not Working via Mamp

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I've been using Mamp 3.5 to create a Wordpress site locally since last week. But all of a sudden I am getting this error while loading:

> localhost:8888/wordpress : "The localhost page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500"

I have no idea what is wrong and what is causing this error. Solutions I've tried already:

- Change ports to 80 and 3306
- Re-install MAMP
- Checked my hosts file for the localhost settings
- Tried using older version of PHP, i.e. 5.6

Comment: Error 500 is usually a programming error. Check your error logs for a more detailed error message.

Comment: I am sorry but I am totally new to this. Where can I find the logs?

Comment: From the **[mamp docs](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp/)** : `The web server (Apache) starts by default on port 8888, the database server ( MySQL) on port 8889. ... All log files are stored in: /Applications/MAMP/logs/ .` A 500 will leave something in error.log on a normal apache (not MAMP), chances are that file exists at the location provided.

Comment: This is the last log recorded in apache_error.log:

[Tue May 17 01:36:54 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/7.0.0 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zh DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the logs. I figured it out, there was a problem in my functions.php file

Answer (score 9):

I have been smashing my head for a while and all the solutions I found on internet didn't help. Finally i did that:

```
tail -n 20 /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log
```

You might have a typo... :P

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For me was to revert the port to 8888. Was following a tutorial sying to change the default port to 80. By reverting to the default one it worked.

Posting anyway in case someone lands here after 4 years.